# How to evaluate the following surface integral?

Tags: surface-integrals, divergence-operator

> > Evaluate $$\iint_S \left (x^4+y^4+z^4 \right )\ dS,$$ where $S=\left \{(x,y,z)\ :\ x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2 \right \},\ a > 0.$

**My attempt** $:$ I have tried to find the integral using [Gauss' divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) which states that

Suppose $V$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ (in this case $n=3,$ which represents the volume of the sphere of radius $a$ centered at the origin) which is compact and has a piecewise smooth boundary $S.$ If $\textbf {F}$ is a continuously differentiable vector field defined on a neighbourhood of $V,$ then

$$\begin{align*} \iiint_V\left(\mathbf{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{F}\right)\,dV & = \iint_{S}(\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n})\,dS  . \end{align*} $$

In this case $\textbf {F} = x^3 \hat {i} + y^3 \hat {j} + z^3 \hat {k},$ which is a continuously differentiable vector field on a neighbourhood of $V$ and $\textbf {n} (x,y,z) = \frac {x \hat i + y \hat j + z \hat k} {a}.$ Hence we have \begin{align*} \iint_S \left (x^4 + y^4 + z^4 \right )\ dS & = a \iiint_V \left (\mathbf {\nabla} \cdot \mathbf {F} \right)\ dV\\ & = a \iiint_V 3 \left (x^2+y^2+z^2 \right )\ dV\\ & = 3a^3 \iiint_V dV \\ & = 3a^3 \times \frac 4 3 \pi a^3 \\ & = 4 \pi a^6. \end{align*}

But the answer given as $\frac {12 \pi} {5} a^6 \neq 4 \pi a^6.$ Where did I do mistake? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

**EDIT** $:$ Here is another way to find the integral. Let $\varphi : [0, \pi] \times [0, 2 \pi] \longrightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be the continuously differentiable parameterization of the given  sphere into spherical coordinates i.e. $$\varphi (u,v) = \left (a \sin u \cos v , a \sin u \sin v , a \cos u \right ),\ (u,v) \in [0, \pi] \times [0, 2 \pi].$$ Then  the above surface integral can be evaluated as follows $:$

Let $F(x,y,z) = x^4 + y^4 + z^4 ,\ (x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3.$ Then we have

$$\begin{align*} \iint_S F(x,y,z)\ dS  & = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} F \left (\varphi (u,v) \right ) \left \| \varphi_u \times \varphi_v \right \|\ du\ dv \\ & = a^6 \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \left (\sin^5 u \cos^4 v + \sin^5 u \sin^4 v + \sin u \cos^4 u \right )\ du\ dv. \end{align*}$$

The computation of  the last integral is not so easy though.

Comment: The point is that $x^2+y^2+z^2$ equals $a^2$ on the surface of the sphere, not inside it, so the equality involving $3a^3 \iiint_V dV$ is not correct.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognize the symmetry to simplify the integral first,

$$I=\int_S \left (x^4+y^4+z^4 \right )\ dS,=3\int_S z^4 \ dS$$

Then, integrate with spherical coordinates $z=a\cos\theta$, $dS = a^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi$,
$$I=3 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}(a\cos\theta)^4 a^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi
=-6\pi a^6 \int_0^{\pi}\cos^4\theta d(\cos\theta)
=\frac{12\pi}5a^6$$

---

Edit:

$$I= 3a \int_V \left (x^2+y^2+z^2 \right )dV =9a\int_V z^2 dV$$
$$=9a\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^a (r\cos\theta)^2 r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi=\frac{12\pi}5a^6$$

Comment: I got your point. Very nicely you have used the symmetry of the sphere. But what's the problem in evaluating the same integral by Gauss' divergence theorem? Can you recognize it?

Comment: @mathmaniac. - It is fine to turn it into a volume integral. But, you made a mistake integrating the volume; you still treated it as a surface one. See my edit in the answer.

Comment: you can also use spherical coordinates to evaluate the volume integral you have written in your edit.

Comment: The entire integrand $x^2+y^2+z^2 = r^2$ when changing cartesian to spherical coordinates.

Comment: So the Jacobian will be multiplied by $r^2$ as integrand.

Comment: @math maniac - that is correct